# What is the difference between using 'init' and 'rd.break' for reseting the root password?

Tags: password, root

I know several ways to reset root user's password, but want to know which is the best and why it is. For example: 
A method:

1. Grub > <kbd>e</kbd>
2. `init=/bin/sh` (Remove `rhgb` and `quiet` tags if necessary) > <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>
3. `/usr/sbin/load_policy -i`
4. `mount -o remount,rw /`
5. `passwd root` or `passwd`
6. `mount -o remount,ro /`

B method:

1. Grub > <kbd>e</kbd>
2. `rd.break` > <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>
3. `mount -o remount,rw /sysroot/`
4. `chroot /sysroot/`
5. `passwd root` or `passwd`
6. `touch /.autorelabel`

Which is the best? Why is it best? I'm preparing for RHCSA (Red Hat Certified System Admin) exam. I need to know the relative merits of each approach. Is one of them more portable? Safer? Is there a reason to choose one over the other?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the best way is as is shown in Red Hat [documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/System_Administrators_Guide/sec-Terminal_Menu_Editing_During_Boot.html#proc-Resetting_the_Root_Password_Using_rd.break).
This is your second method. For GRUB2/RHEL7 single/emergency mode should not work since it will use `sulogin` to authenticate you before presenting the command prompt.

So lets mark off different methods.

1. For RHEL5, RHEL6, append `1`, `s` or `init=/bin/bash` to kernel cmdline
2. For RHEL7, RHEL8, CentOS7, CentOS8, append `rd.break` or `init=/bin/bash` to kernel cmdline

It appears that the second method is not available on RHEL5 and RHEL6. But for RHEL7 I will prefer the first because adding init=/bin/bash is a bit tricky when single mode is password protected and may be appending `rd.break` is a way to standardize it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @taliezin. Both work for me. First method is also shown in documentation: http://red.ht/1vHVatu.

Comment: @taliezin  what is the full meaning of `rd` in  `rd.break`?

Comment: @SIslam, `rd.break` - drop to a shell at the end. More info you can find [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/dracut.cmdline.7.html).

Comment: What does `chroot /sysroot/` do?

Comment: @SnowCrash, as `rd.break` asks for a break at an early stage of the boot process then after mounting as read/write  you have to `chroot` to it, more info for `chroot` you can read [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot)

Comment: Documentation link is now 404 unfortunately :/

Answer (score 4):

The ‘rd’ part of ‘rd.break’ refers to ramdisk— the initial ramdisk (initrd) environment.

The second method (using rd.break) is preferable for RHEL7. Some systems (with a USB keyboard or a VM) don’t actually seem to set the password when you reboot. Possibly it’s only setting the password for /etc/shadow inside the ramdisk, and not the one you were expecting.

What that has to do with a USB keyboard I don’t know, but that’s what the knowledge base arrival says, and what my experience to date has been. I rather suspect this has more to do with whether your root filesystem is on LVM (hint: dracut)