# change root password in CentOS 7

Tags: centos, password, grub, root

I was reading about changing root password in CentOS 7. it's totally different from centOS 6.

[change root password](https://www.unixmen.com/reset-root-password-centos-7/)

I was wondering about the steps for example why should I change `ro`? what exactly happens in every step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ro` option means `read-only`, so changing to `rw init=/sysroot/bin/sh` in kernel-image will open a shell and now your file-system is mounted with `read and write`.

Now `chroot /sysroot` means that `/sysroot` directory will appear as `/`.
For more info regarding this read this answer https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/413790/255251.

Comment: The difference is due to the change in init systems between CentOS 6 and 7.